# How to get ETHER off the chain and into account?

Tags: accounts

I did a test and sent ETH (6) to my ETH account, but they dont show up in the account balance, however ETH and ETC both show on the etherscan.io
 how do I get them in the account and I never set up a wallet because it says I need to have a balance before I can make that contract... so I could goto myetherwallet and make a seperate wallet for free by following instructions/zip offline etc. but I still dont know how to take my ETH and ETC off the chain, I have a bit of ETH on coinbase but no address to send it to yet...besides the one i cant get off da chain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take Ether "off" the block chain as that would invalidate the paradigm itself. What you mean is send them to an account whose private key you have access to (typically managed by a client/wallet) so that you can further use the balance for future transactions.

Do you have the private key for the addresses you sent the Ether to? If not, then you cannot recover the balance.

Comment: thanks sabi, the "account"/address is my main account set up when i first downloaded ethereum and is password protected, but cant access from office, where I am now, if anyone, perhaps you could at some point walk me thru I'd be forever grateful

Comment: What do you mean by can't access it? Have you removed the account files (they are stored in the `keystore` directory inside the data directory the Ethereum client is set to use). Point the client (geth, eth, pyethapp, etc.) to that directory and then unlock the account through the client's IPC interface.

Comment: funny, thanks, while I was away seeing patients I figured out where it is but as of now at work dont have access at office. will do and let you know later today(evening)

Comment: Sebi, I got it done unlocked......sheesh was not hard with the keys, thanks again